# Python Async what is causing the memory leak?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I am downloading zip files and looking inside them to check their contents for a few million items, but I am constantly accruing memory and I will eventually go OOM, even with small semaphores.

Consider the block:

```
    async def zip_reader(self, blobFileName, blobEndPoint, semaphore):

        try:
            # access blob
            async with ClientSecretCredential(TENANT, CLIENTID, CLIENTSECRET) as credential:
                async with BlobServiceClient(account_url="https://blob1.blob.core.windows.net/", credential=credential, max_single_get_size=64 * 1024 * 1024, max_chunk_get_size=32 * 1024 * 1024) as blob_service_client:
                    async with blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=blobEndPoint, blob=blobFileName) as blob_client:
                        async with semaphore:
                            logger.info(f"Starting: {blobFileName}, {blobEndPoint}")

                            # open bytes
                            writtenbytes = io.BytesIO()

                            # write file to it
                            stream = await blob_client.download_blob(max_concurrency=25)
                            stream = await stream.readinto(writtenbytes)

                            # zipfile
                            f = ZipFile(writtenbytes)

                            # file list
                            file_list = [s for s in f.namelist()]

                            # send to df
                            t_df = pd.DataFrame({'fileList': file_list})

                            # add fileName
                            t_df['blobFileName'] = blobFileName
                            t_df['blobEndPoint'] = blobEndPoint

                            if semaphore.locked():
                                await asyncio.sleep(1)

                            logger.info(f"Completed: {blobFileName}")

                            # clean up here; also tried del on objs here as well
                            self.cleanup()

                            return t_df


    async def cleanup(self):
        gc.collect()
        await asyncio.sleep(1)


    async def async_file_as_bytes_generator(self, blobFileName, blobEndPoint, semaphore):
        """
        main caller
        """
        semaphore = asyncio.Semaphore(value=semaphore)
        return await asyncio.gather(*[self.zip_reader(fn, ep, semaphore) for fn, ep in zip(blobFileName, blobEndPoint)], # also tried attaching here)
```

Comment: I see nothing wrong. you are checking files asynchronously so should be loaded in memory for every file until it's done and would cause that probably.

Comment: your code there is incomplete - and the problem may lie in the part we can't see.

For one: there i sno `except`  or `finally`   counterpart to the `try` statement in your function. Also, please include the code for the inports and a program entry point calling `async_file_as_bytes_generator` so that this is  a self contained example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`asyncio.gather` has no strategy to limit the number of simultaneous tasks in execution at all. Your semaphore may limit how many are being fetched and processed at once - but gather will wait for all data frames to be avalible, and return all at once.

Instead of using a single `await asyncio.gather`  use something like `asyncio.wait` with a timeout, and keep control of how many tasks are running, yielding the complete dataframes as they become ready.

And then, you didn't show the remaining of your program leading to the call to `async_file_as_bytes_generator`, but it will have to consume the  dataframes as they are yielded and dispose of them, of course.

Also: no need to do explicit calls to `gc.collect` ever: this is a no-operation. Python does free your memory if your program is correct, and keep no references to objects consuming it. Otherwise there is nothing `gc.collect` could do anyway.

Your "main caller" can be something along this - but as I denoted, you have to check the code that calls it so that it consumes each dataframe at once, and not expect a list with all dataframes as your current code do.

```
async def async_file_as_bytes_generator(self, blobFileName, blobEndPoint, task_limit):
    """
    main caller
    """
    semaphore = asyncio.Semaphore(value=task_limit)
    
    all_tasks = {self.zip_reader(fn, ep, semaphore) for fn, ep in zip(blobFileName, blobEndPoint)}
    current_tasks = set()
    while all_tasks or current_tasks:
        while all_tasks and len(current_tasks < task_limit):
            current_tasks.add(all_tasks.pop())
            
        done, incomplete = await asyncio.wait(current_tasks, return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)
        for task in done:
            # optionally check for task exception
            yield task.result()
        current_tasks = incomplete
```

Comment: Thanks for the kind help! Any chance you could elaborate on using the function with `yield`? If I create a loop, `loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()` and then `loop.run_until_complete(async_file_as_bytes_generator(blobFileNameSet, blobEndPointSet, 4))` -- I get `TypeError: An asyncio.Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is required`.

Comment: you have to use it from an async function - there, the easiest way is by using an `async for` statement as in `async for dataframe in async_file_as_bytes_generator(blobFileNameSet, blobEndPointSet, 4):` - then do whatver you need with the dataframe in the `async for` body, except keeping it around in memory in a list of dict.

Comment: When I run this, `async for dataframe in async_file_as_bytes_generator(blobFileNameSet, blobEndPointSet, 4): print(dataframe.shape)` I get `'set' object has no attribute 'result'` -- any idea how it is returning the set rather than the df?

Comment: yes. it is a typo in the answer, as can be clearly seem when one knows how `for` works. It should be `yield task.result()` not `done.result()`